Ubuntu 24.10 not giving me Wayland/Xorg option on login screen
I recently upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10.  Before the upgrade I was using Wayland.  Since the upgrade my system is using X11.  The login screen no longer gives the control allowing me to choose between the two.  Even though I have enabled Wayland in my GDM3 configuration the system still boots into X11.  How can I get Wayland back? Thank you.
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-11-22 14:30:34

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              System76 Thelio Mira
Memory:                                      128.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Core™ i9-14900K × 32
Graphics:                                    NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 4070 Ti SUPER
Disk Capacity:                               4.1 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            FH Z5
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.10
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               47
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.11.0-9-generic

Here is a screen shot (literally using my phone) of the log in screen:
Login screen shot
As you can see no gear wheel icon (as there used to be with 24.04)

Welcome to Ask. The Wayland/Xorg11 selection is only shown when you select the usr/pword from the login screen. Did you miss this step? It is possible that the NVIDIA graphics forces Xorg.X11.

use Log Out to get to the point at which you enter your user name requiring your password and the gear wheel icon is shown in the bottom right hand corner of the screen. Clcik on that to select your option and then proceed with your password entry

Thank you @david and graham.  I have edited the post to attach a screen shot showing the absence of the gear wheel icon.  I could find no one with a similar issue after searching online.

press ctrl+alt+f3 for tty then uncomment 'WaylandEnable=false' in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

With your highlight on the password field (as shown in you pic.) type the TAB once (should select the gear, even if it is off screen), and then type Enter, which should produce the list to choose xorg/wayland/... Choose the non-xorg choice, since Wayland is the default and may just say "Ubuntu" for that choice.
